# Exception while connecting through Spring Data to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-java

I am working on some test program for `SpringData` `MongoDB`, I have done it same as it's mentioned on http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/html/#mongo.core.  But it's showing exceptions:

```
package com.springMongo.core;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;

import com.springMongo.config.MongoConfig;
import com.springMongo.person.Person;



public class MongoApp {

  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MongoApp.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoConfig.class);
    MongoOperations mongoOps = ctx.getBean(MongoOperations.class);

    mongoOps.insert(new Person("1234", "Joe"));

    log.info(mongoOps.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("Joe")), Person.class));
  }

}



package com.springMongo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;

/**
 * Spring MongoDB configuration file
 * 
 */
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  @Override
  public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    return new Mongo("128.0.0.1",10001);
  }

  @Override
  public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo() , "try_db");
  }

@Override
public String getDatabaseName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}






package com.springMongo.person;

public class Person {

      private String id;

      private String name;

      public Person(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
      }

      public String getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
      }

    }
```

But after running MongoApp.java, I am getting following exception:

```
Jan 3, 2012 12:41:28 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7c64dc11: startup date [Tue Jan 03 12:41:28 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 3, 2012 12:41:29 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2b275d39: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,mongoConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,mongo,mongoTemplate,mongoDbFactory,mongoMappingContext,mappingMongoConverter]; root of factory hierarchy
Jan 3, 2012 12:41:29 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2b275d39: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,mongoConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,mongo,mongoTemplate,mongoDbFactory,mongoMappingContext,mappingMongoConverter]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class com.springMongo.config.MongoConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration.mongoDbFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
    at com.springMongo.core.MongoApp.main(MongoApp.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration.mongoDbFactory() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration.mongoDbFactory(AbstractMongoConfiguration.java:54)
    at com.springMongo.config.MongoConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2129bffe.CGLIB$mongoDbFactory$3(<generated>)
    at com.springMongo.config.MongoConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2129bffe$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7ac56fd1.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
    at com.springMongo.config.MongoConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2129bffe.mongoDbFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Bad IP address? 128.0.0.1 should be 127.0.0.1
- You need to specify database name via `getDatabaseName()`