# Error when trying to send data from the spring application to mongodb on remote server

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to create a website that will connect to the databases on the external host. For this purpose, I created two virtual machines. One contains the MongoDB database, and the other one contains the website created in spring-boot + react. I am currently at the stage of creating a RestController. I got this error when trying to send a test request:

```
2020-10-25 17:39:38.492 ERROR 25849 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='', source='', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='', source='', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: databaseName is not empty
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrueArgument(Assertions.java:101) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoNamespace.checkDatabaseNameValidity(MongoNamespace.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoNamespace.<init>(MongoNamespace.java:108) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.getCommandMessage(CommandHelper.java:89) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$100(SaslAuthenticator.java:40) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:54) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:47) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:207) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:47) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticate(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:152) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:61) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:50) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:435) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:102) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:90) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:119) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:628) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:625) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:462) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:625) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:77) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:190) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2782) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2518) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2500) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:856) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:383) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:205) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:55) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.project.videoSerwis.services.RoleService.getRoles(RoleService.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.project.videoSerwis.controller.VideoServiceController.getRoles(VideoServiceController.java:93) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_265]
```

**I test Request with swagger.**

From what I understand, the application is connecting to the database but cannot see my database. That's why I put a test insert to force db to show up in the `show dbs`.

```
admin      0.000GB
config     0.000GB
local      0.000GB
projectdb  0.000GB
```

However, it did not help.

You can see my application.properties below.

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=
spring.data.mongodb.database=projectdb
spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy=
spring.data.mongodb.grid-fs-database=
spring.data.mongodb.host=172.25.1.5
spring.data.mongodb.password=
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=
```

Below is my RestController, I don't know if it will be useful but still I add it.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public class VideoServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService iUserService;

    @Autowired
    private IRoleService iRoleService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/postUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void postUser(@ModelAttribute UserPOJO userPOJO) {


        iUserService.postUser(userPOJO);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<UserPOJO> getUsers() {


        return iUserService.getUserPojo();

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUsersById", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public UserPOJO getUsersById(@RequestParam("Id") String id) {


        return iUserService.getUserById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUserByEmailAndPass", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public UserPOJO getUserByEmailAndPass(@RequestParam("email") String email,
                                      @RequestParam("password") String password) {



        return iUserService.getUserByEmailAndPassword(email,password);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/putPassword", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public void putPassword(@RequestParam("id") String id,@RequestParam("newPass") String newPass,
                            @RequestParam("oldPass") String oldPass) {

        iUserService.putPassword(id,newPass,oldPass);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteUser", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean deleteUser(@RequestParam("id") String id) {

        return iUserService.deleteUser(id);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/postRole", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void postRole(@ModelAttribute RolePOJO role) {



        iRoleService.postRole(role);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getRoles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<RolePOJO> getRoles() {



        return iRoleService.getRoles();

    }
    //5eca9ef4bf824a6544b732a5 USER
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteRole", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean deleteRole(@RequestParam("id") String id) {



        return iRoleService.deleteRole(id);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/putUserRole", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public void putUserRole(@RequestParam("userId") String userId, @RequestParam("roleName") String roleName) {

        iUserService.putUserRole(userId, roleName);


    }


}
```

I can definitely connect with both hosts, I have already tested this. **Has anyone had such problems and could advise on how to fix it?**

**Edit 1**

After replacing these lines:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=projectdb
spring.data.mongodb.host=172.25.1.5
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

With:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://172.25.1.5:27017/projectdb
```

This error began to appear (There were more errors, but all the others were caused by this one):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.validateConfiguration(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:79) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.computeClientSettings(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:68) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:61) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:57) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

I am also adding my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>videoSerwis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>videoSerwis</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Edit 2**

This topic: [Spring Boot setting up MongoDB repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819112/spring-boot-setting-up-mongodb-repository) unfortunately, it cannot help me. It mentions adding the name of the database but I already added it as I wrote in the commentary. Something else must be causing this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot setting up MongoDB repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819112/spring-boot-setting-up-mongodb-repository)

Comment: This might be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709049/exception-while-connecting-through-spring-data-to-mongodb

Comment: @Aman and @AlexisG I have already checked these topics, but the problem there was not giving the name of the database. However, I provided it here: `spring.data.mongodb.database=projectdb`. After I added this: `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://172.25.1.5:27017/projectdb` the error has changed. I will add a error to the topic in the edit.

Comment: Replace the **uri** with `mongodb://username:password@172.25.1.5:27017/projectdb`

Comment: @Aman I don't have a user or password. First I created them, but when the error started to show up, I removed them. I wanted to see if it would help. Unfortunately not. The same errors appeared

Comment: You can also see this post about configuration: [How to initialize MongoClient once in spring boot and export it to use its methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663741/how-to-initialize-mongoclient-once-in-spring-boot-and-export-it-to-use-its-metho/61677205#61677205)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following config class from the documentation:

```
@Configuration
class ApplicationConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

  
  @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
  public String mongoUri;

  @Override
  protected void configureClientSettings(MongoClientSettings.Builder builder) {
      builder.applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(mongoUri));
  }

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return "projectdb";
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try it tomorow and tell if it helped.

Comment: It worked. I just had to remove `@EnableMongoRepositories`. This caused spring to stop seeing my repositories.

Comment: Worked for me too . I didn't have to disable ```@EnableMongoRepositories```.

Answer (score 0):

If coming from SpringBoot 3.1.0...It's a known error and reported [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35566).

workaround is add the Db name in the uri itself.Example below. Worked for me

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=demo-db
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27018/${spring.data.mongodb.database}?readPreference=primaryPreferred&directConnection=true
```